# After about 30 seconds, my batch file closes itself

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My file is designed to copy itself, and then rename all batch files in the directory. Because it does this endlessly, I have it loop copying the file, and then it renames it.
It just quits after a while, though.

Here is my code:

```
@echo off 
:place1 

xcopy /y C:\ProgramData\Windows_PowerShell\Win_PowerShell.bat C:\USer\Enterusername\Desktop\Afolder\%random%*.bat 

cd C:\Users\Enterusername\Desktop\Afolder\ 
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion  
set "chars=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"  
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *bat') do call :renameFile "%%F"  
exit /b  
:renameFile  
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion  
:retry  
set "name="  
for /l %%N in (1 1 8) do (  
  set /a I=!random!%%36  
  for %%I in (!I!) do set "name=!name!!chars:~%%I,1!"  
)  
echo if exist !name!.bat goto :retry  
endlocal & ren %1 %name%.bat 

goto place1
```

Comment: Just glancing at your code, it's probably the `setlocal disableDelayedExpansion` line getting run too many times. After `setlocal` is run a certain number of times, the batch script aborts due to excessive call stack depth. You don't need that line, so just delete it.

Comment: The `goto place1` should be replaced with a `Goto :eof` You created an infinitive loop never returning to the `for /f`

Comment: Maximum `setlocal` depth is 32, but it only results in a message, not a crash.