# How to individually rename the files in each separate folder in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, rename

with the batch file below, I numerically rename all the .mp4 files in the folders, incremented by 1, but it doesn't rename them as I would like.

```
@Set "count=0"
@For /F "Delims=" %%I In ('Dir /B/S/A-D-S "*.mp4" 2^>NUL')Do @(
    For %%J In ("%%~pI.")Do @(Set /A count+=1
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Ren "%%I" "!count!%%~xI"
        EndLocal))
@Pause
```

Now the rename is like this:

1. Folder1 (60 files in it)

   - 1.mp4, 2.mp4....60.mp4
2. Folder2 (60 files in it)

   - 61.mp4, 62.mp4....120.mp4
3. Folder3 (30 files in it)

   - 121.mp4, 122.mp4....160.mp4

**But I would like to be**

1. Folder1 (60 files in it)

   - 1.mp4, 2.mp4....60.mp4
2. Folder2 (60 files in it)

   - 1.mp4, 2.mp4....60.mp4
3. Folder2 (30 files in it)

   - 1.mp4, 2.mp4....30.mp4
4. Folder2 (45 files in it)

   - 1.mp4, 2.mp4....45.mp4

Each sub-folder should start renaming from 1 and end at how many files are in the folder.

Can someone help me in this direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the following modification would suit your needs:

```bash
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /A:D-S /B /S 2^>NUL') Do @(
    Set "Count=0"
    For /F "Delims=" %%H In (
        'Set "PathExt=" ^& %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe "%%G":"*.mp4" 2^>NUL'
    ) Do @(
        Set /A Count += 1
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Ren "%%H" "!Count!%%~xH"
        EndLocal
    )
)
@Pause
```

Comment: Something strange happens, all my files are deleted under the following conditions. The batch file you made works and renames exactly as I need, but when I use another batch file, I remove the files from the folder and rename them, then delete folders and the random renaming of the mp4 files. I have been using this batch for a long time and it works perfectly, but in combination with your batch, it deletes my .mp4 files

Comment: This is the batch I run after your batch `@echo off

set "dest=\"
set "source="
set "chars=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
for /r "%source%" %%d in (*) do move "%%d"  "%dest%"
FOR /F delims^= %%A IN ('DIR/AD/B/S^|SORT/R') DO RD "%%A"

for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s /a-d *.mp4') do call :renameFile "%%F"
exit /b

:renameFile
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:retry
set "name="
for /l %%N in (1 1 8) do (
  set /a I=!random!%%36
  for %%I in (!I!) do set "name=!name!!chars:~%%I,1!"
)
echo if exist !name!.mp4 goto :retry
endlocal & ren %1 %name%.mp4
`

Comment: @IonutBejinariu, if my answer works, it works,. What happens afterwards, when you run somebody elses' code is not my concern and irrelevant. I am not providing you with support for another batch file, as part of my assistance in solving your question.

Comment: you are absolutely right, but what would be the connection? only in relation to the batch file from you behaves like this... should I open a new question?

Comment: Do whatever you want @IonutBejinariu, but do not post my batch file anywhere within that question. The only connection, it has to that code is you!

Comment: As a side note what you've posted above, @IonutBejinariu, bears a marked similarity to [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43660428), which also has an unanswered problem.

Comment: I realized, actually when I move the .mp4 from the folders, it was normal for all the files 1.mp4, 2.mp4 .. 20.mp4 to all similar name from other folders to be in conflict... I can't believe that I didn't  realized from the first. So before I move files from folder I will use the first batch in this Question and after that I move de files in root folder.